# RoR: Linking to a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, view-helpers

I am trying to create a link on the "index of tickets" to link to "edit" page. (Pls see picture below)
Right now I can type "0.0.0.0:3000/tickets/1/edit" to go to edit page.
However, i'm not sure how to link to this page.
Would you pls give me some pointers?

Thank you for the guidance.

Note:
I am learning RoR & creating this page based on raistutorial.org

[image: I am stuck at the location of the following picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'edit', edit_ticket_path(ticket) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you follow the convention of using resourceful routes in your `config/routes.rb`, according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, then you benefit for having nice path and url helpers available.

To see what paths are available, just run `rake routes`, and you'll see output like:

```
% rake routes

    tickets GET    /tickets(.:format)          tickets#index
            POST   /tickets(.:format)          tickets#create
 new_ticket GET    /tickets/new(.:format)      tickets#new
edit_ticket GET    /tickets/:id/edit(.:format) tickets#edit
     ticket GET    /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#show
            PUT    /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#update
            DELETE /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#destroy
```

From this, we can see that there's a named route `edit_ticket`, so we can use the `edit_ticket_path` or `edit_ticket_url` helpers (the latter will include the domain name, and is useful for things like emails).

It's useful to compare the output of `rake routes` to what you have in your `config/routes.rb` to make sure you have a good understanding of rails conventions and resourceful routes.

Comment: Thank you Ben for introducing "rake routes". This would be very helpful to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to edit_ticket_path(ticket) %>
```

One tip how you could have found this out yourself: if you use scaffold, there's an edit link on the show.html.erb page - you could have just used this as an example exchanging the instance of ticket it is referring to.

Note: the :method option for link_to refers to the http method, which can be GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, but not the controller action!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tips about scaffold. I learnt something new :)

Answer (score 0):

The `:method` attribute specifies the HTTP attribute, that's to say POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE, HEAD and whatsoever.

Here you need to provide a path to the ticket edit link in the second parameter.

That can be done like this :

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_ticket_path(ticket) %>
```

However when you do just `<%= link_to "show", ticket %>`, Rails automatically infers it's the show page you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer & explanation about :method attribute specifies HTTP attribute :)